# Problem export product - no valid data sent

Tags: magento-1.9, export, importexport

I need to export all the products in Magento 1.9 with the module Mage_ImportExport, but in `export setting` when I select `product` as `Entity Type`, Magento doesn't load any `Entity Attributes`.

So when I click on "Continue" I get the error "No valid data sent"

I've checked the web server log file that gives this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getName() on a non-object app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 171
```

the error part of that `Product.php` is:

```
   /**
 * Initialize categories ID to text-path hash.
 *
 * @return Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product
 */
protected function _initCategories()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addNameToResult();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        $structure = preg_split('#/+#', $category->getPath());
        $pathSize  = count($structure);
        if ($pathSize > 1) {
            $path = array();
            for ($i = 1; $i < $pathSize; $i++) {
                $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
            }
            $this->_rootCategories[$category->getId()] = array_shift($path);
            if ($pathSize > 2) {
                $this->_categories[$category->getId()] = implode('/', $path);
            }
        }

    }
    return $this;
}
```

and the line 171 is:

```
 $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
```

any suggestions?

Comment: In export, when you change 'Entity Type' to Product one Ajax request will call. check in console and see what response is coming in that Ajax call. Is there any error in that call?

Comment: Thank you @AkhileshPatel you're right, i get an error in Ajax call, error `500 Internal Server Error`, but if i select customer instead product it works, the problem is only for Ajax call of products. What could be the reason?

Comment: Okay...that could be a time out issue. How many do you have custom attributes? Add set_time_limit(0); in your index.php and check again.

Comment: I have a few custom attributes just 2 or 3 not more. I updated the question, i double checked the web server log and get the error that I wrote above. It seems an error with category ID, could it be?

Comment: Also try to enable error reporting, and if Mod_Security is enabled you might to want to whitelist the ajax url. Mod security can be picky when it comes to ajax or post requests.

Comment: when i try to export minimum no.of products like 100's of products, export working, otherwise when i try to export whole my products (in my site 20,000 products) i get no valid data send error
one thing sure, my export working good,  what is the remaining error

Comment: @JeevaRathinam probably is a time out problem. After a certain time the server stops the process. For those amount of products, I highly suggest to use **dataflow profile** to export

Comment: @Xavier : i get error like this when i try to what you suggest...

Comment: @Xavier : http://i.imgur.com/PkRsHxQ.png

Comment: @JeevaRathinam but are you using the "dataflow profile" or the default magento "Export"?

Comment: @Xavier : dataflow profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before this try please try to do re-index data and check again.**

The issue is $structure[$i] that is entity_id (category id) passing in this function. It seems entity_id is not a valid in catalog_category_entity or category flat tables.

Check in your database if your flat tables are fine.

Alternative but a not a good solution.

```
$path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
```

Replace this with

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($structure[$i]);
$path[] = $category->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why you said "not a good solution" what could be the problem of that solution?

Comment: Great, actually we are passing category id in function getItemById() and which is try to get category name by calling getName() and we are getting non object fatal error. the issue is somewhere in your flat data. we should find out exact problem in database which needs much debug effort. But anyways this will also work for you. Basically it's just returning category name which you will get in csv export!! :)

Comment: I tried to check entity_id in the database table (catalog_category_entity and flat_store), but they seem to be all ok, do you know if exist, a quicker way to find out the faulty id?

Comment: I don't know the exact solution that is why I mention we needs to debug in deep :)

Comment: its not work for me, could pls guide me

Comment: are you using flat tables ?

Comment: yes, am using flat tables

Comment: After correction, i get same error,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Magento website, and got resolved with the help of Hosting provider, Try This.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush

Best Regards
Shaik