# How can i solve - No valid data sent - Error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, importexport, export

I am export my products after hosting its not working, but from my `localhost` its `working fine`. I can not export from import/export,

```
am increased max_exe_time
```

> my store consist 30,000 products

```
When i try to export products, am faced 500 internal error
```

[image]

Comment: You can check this post. May I help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85174/problem-export-product-no-valid-data-sent

Comment: chat   @   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42380/no-valid-data-send-error

Comment: Check `max_execution_time` is not too short in `.htaccess`

Comment: in my site max_execution_time 8048m, but not working

Comment: For Product Bulk import use magmi. https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ download magmi and use this your max execution time error not come.

Comment: i need bulk export

Answer (score 1):

Probably the export execution hit the max_execution_time or memory_limit limits set by php.
However, if your application uses Apache as a webserver, you should be able to modify these limits by setting them in your .htaccess.

```
#Increase the memory limito to 1G
php_value memory_limit 1G

# Define the script timeout after 1 hour
php_value max_execution_time 3600

# If Magento fails after submitting a form you may need to tune the input limits

php_value post_max_size 5M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value max_input_time 300
```

After editing the .htaccess, upload it in the Magento root.

## Warning:

errors in the .htaccess file may lead to unreachable (error 500) website. Test it locally before uploading it.

Comment: not working....

Comment: So, you have to look in your Hosting panel for the error_log report and check if something is reported in there

Answer (score 1):

According to the code, there's two possible reasons behind the **No valid data sent** error:

```
public function exportAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            /** @var $model Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export */
            $model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());

            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                $model->getContentType()
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
    }
    return $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

### Reason 1: An exception has been thrown

This corresponds to this bit of code:

```
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
```

So you're getting this default message but that does not tell you what happened.

Fortunately the `Mage::logException` line automatically logs the exception into the exception file which is `var/log/exception.log` by default.

So I suggest you find out what the exception is by checking this file and edit your question with the exception that will help us fixing your issue.

### Reason 2: The request does not contain the export_filter data

In case you don't have anything in your `var/log/exception.log` file that means that no exception is being thrown and thus this is the following condition that is not matched:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP))
```

My suggestion in this case is to check the content of the request by adding:

```
Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getPost());
```

Right before the condition and then check in `var/log/system.log` to see what the request contains.

If you get the error that means the request does not contain an entry called `export_filter`

The main reason I can think of is that **maybe the PHP maximum POST size is reached** and thus you need to increase the PHP variables mentionned by Fabian:

```
post_max_size=1024M
```

I highly doubt you have to deal with `upload_max_filesize` as you're doing an export here and not an import.

Comment: I get same error.

Comment: @JeevaRathinam well what did you do ? Did you follow my guide for reason 1 ?

Comment: yes, am increased  post_max_size, upload_max_filesize

Comment: @JeevaRathinam please read my answer and follow the steps in reason 1. What do you get in `var/log/exception.log`

Comment: but, when i export from local host, i get what i want,

Comment: okay, let me check

Comment: @JeevaRathinam well that's not the point. Please answer my question and tell what's in `var/log/exception`

Comment: @  Raphael at Digital Pianism : This is because of my Internet speed, when I try my 4G Network it's working, 3g Internet speed getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue. I disable DeveloperMode in Magento 1 by using:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
```

in file `index.php`

Comment: Not working, i get same error

Answer (score 0):

Normally this means, that the uploaded file is not there.

There are two settings which need to be increased:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Make sure, both settings are greater than your file size.

If you get a response from the server it is **NOT `max_execution_time`**, if php kills his process due to the execution time, you get a white page, a apache/nginx 500 or whatever. No magento page.

Comment: not working....