# Products Direct Export Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, export

How can I solve direct export error. My store consisting 20k products and I know it's huge.

How can I solve this export error?

> max_execution_time : 99999999; max_input_time : 16000; memory_limit 
>   : 8048M

Output Screen Shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not choosing entity type while exporting,please try to choose correct option and then submit.If you still getting any error then let us know with log details.

Comment: guys, the error comes after selected everything, selected entity type as products and click continue then only getting an error like no valid data send error,

Comment: Try that solution,hope it will help you  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/85177

Comment: Already I tried above one, still products export not working, did you ever tried 20k products export using direct export?

Answer (score 0):

you can try an Alternative way as below  :

Go to **System > Import/Export > Dataflow Profile** > than you can see "**Export all Products**".

[image]

once you click on that go to "Run Profile" & click on "**Run Profile in Pop up**"

[image]

Comment: This one also not working, in my store 20k products., and my php related memory high, still not exporting.

Comment: @zus contact hosting providers once.....

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the reason, it's all about because of server requirements,

**before I have 4GB VPS server**, now I **updated to 8GB VPS server**, now its working good.

Thank you all for your valuable times.